# Parse: Saving data to the main "User" class

Tags: parse-platform

I just have basic code for testing purposes.

```
let user = PFObject(className: "User")
user["email"] = userEmail
user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    ....
}
```

But I always get this result.

[image]

Is the main User class named differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `PFUser` rather than creating a `PFObject` with the classname of "User"

```
let user = PFUser()
user["email"] = userEmail
user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    ...
}
```

Comment: I actually had to use user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock instead of user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock, but thanks for PSUser().